# Not able to embed Jupyterlab running on Jupyterhub into an iframe

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am trying to integrate jupyterlab running with jupyterhub into an iframe. 
I made all the required changes in the configuration files.
In the jupyter_notebook_config.py I have made the following changes.

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {'headers': {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Security-Policy': 'frame-ancestors http://localhost:9005'
  }}
```

while in the jupyterhub_config.py I have added the following

```
c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {'headers': {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Security-Policy': 'frame-ancestors http://localhost:9005'
  }}
```

But still, when I try to open http://localhost:8002/user/admin/lab URL in the iframe I get the following error

`Refused to display 'http://localhost:8002/user/admin/lab' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".`

Can someone let me know if I am missing something or is there an issue with my configuration?

Comment: Iframe behavior might be different for different browsers, e.g. firefox vs chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a work around,

- Have a common notebook configuration file for all the users who
  log into Jupyterhub.
- Pass the configuration file as spawner args.

Follow the procedure below:

1. Create a file named jupyter_notebook_config.py in a specific location say /home/shared_config/

> You can either create the file manually using a text editor like vim
>   or generate a default coinfig file using jupyter notebook with the
>   following command

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

> Note that the above command requires jupyter notebook to be installed
>   (pip3 install jupyterhub notebook)
>
> After the installation if you face an error related to ruamel.yaml
>   version on loading the tljh-config, execute the following command:
>   pip3 install ruamel.yaml==0.15.*

2. Open the jupyter_notebook_config.py file that you created above and add the following code:

   c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings={'headers': {'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors * 'self' "}}

> change the permission of the file using the following code:

```
chmod -R 755 /home/shared_config/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

3. Open you jupyterhub configuration file (by default located in /opt/tljh/config/jupyterhub_config.d/jupyterhub_config.py) and add the following code:

> Note: you can generate jupyterhub configuration file using the
>   following command: jupyterhub --generate-config

```
c.Spawner.args = [ '--config=/home/shared_config/jupyter_notebook_config.py']
```

4. Reload the tljf-config using the following command:

   sudo tljf-config reload

Happy coding !!

**Here is what my config looks like**

**-- /opt/tljh/config/jupyterhub_config.d/jupyterhub_config.py**

```
c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {'headers': {'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors * 'self' "}}
c.Spawner.args = [ '--config=/home/ubuntu/jupyter_notebook_config.py']
```

**-- /home/shared_config/jupyter_notebook_config.py**

```
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings={'headers': {'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors * 'self' "}}
```

**Some useful references and related issues:**

- https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/config-basics.html
- https://minrk-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html
- https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/spawners-basics.html
- https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/335
- https://github.com/jupyterhub/the-littlest-jupyterhub/issues/312
- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3904
- https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/379

Comment: I tried the above approach, but I am still facing the same error. I am using a simple HTML file for the iframe. What should the frame ancestor value be for that?

Comment: try this : <iframe src="http://localhost:8002/user/admin/lab" width="1300px" height="600px" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-modals" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

Comment: I am running jupyterhub on a separate machine. I tried <iframe src="http://10.201.11.44:8002/user/admin/lab" width="1300px" height="600px" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-modals" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe> . But still im facing the same issue.     Refused to display 'http://10.201.11.44:8002/hub/login?next=%2Fhub%2Fuser%2Fadmin%2Flab' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors * 'self'".

Comment: I got the iframe to work, I am now getting the login page. But as soon as i try logging in, I get the following error :- Blocked autofocusing on a form control in a cross-origin subframe.

Comment: This is how I was able to achieve the iframe embed. I followed the installation tutorial here : tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest , then did the above work around. Make sure to add an letsencrypt free ssl certificate - tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/admin/https.html – Amal Vijayan